How to add labels to 3D Axis in pyqtgraph
I would like to add labels to a 3D axis drawn in GLViewWidget from pyqtgraph.opengl. I followed the example  but did not manage to make it work properly. When I subclass the GLViewWidget object and overwrite the paintGL() method, it says that there are not any self.qglColor and self.renderText attributes inherited from the parent ('MyGLView' object has no attribute 'qglColor'; 'MyGLView' object has no attribute 'renderText').
Here is the code:
from pyqtgraph.opengl import GLViewWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont, QColor, QFontMetrics
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication


class MyGLView(GLViewWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def paintGL(self, *args, **kwargs):
        GLViewWidget.paintGL(self, *args, **kwargs)

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Tahoma")
        font.setPixelSize(21)
        font.setBold(True)

        title_str = 'Screen Coordinates'
        metrics = QFontMetrics(font)
        m = metrics.boundingRect(title_str)
        width = m.width()
        height = m.height()

        scrn_sz_width = self.size().width()

        self.qglColor(QColor(255, 255, 0, 255))
        self.renderText((scrn_sz_width-width)/2, height+5, title_str, font)


app = QApplication([])
fig1 = MyGLView()
fig1.show()

Any suggestion whether I am just using wrong version (0.13.3) of pyqtgraph? If that is the case can I just make it work without downgrading/upgrading?

You have to use QPainter  to paint in paintGL method.
Here is an example you can use:
from pyqtgraph.opengl import GLViewWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QFont, QColor, QFontMetrics, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication


class MyGLView(GLViewWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def paintGL(self, *args, **kwargs):
        GLViewWidget.paintGL(self, *args, **kwargs)

        painter = QPainter(self)

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily("Tahoma")
        font.setPixelSize(21)
        font.setBold(True)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(255, 255, 0, 255)))
        painter.setFont(font)

        title_str = 'Screen Coordinates'
        metrics = QFontMetrics(font)
        m = metrics.boundingRect(title_str)
        width = m.width()
        height = m.height()

        scrn_sz_width = self.size().width()
        painter.drawText(int((scrn_sz_width - width) / 2), height + 5, width, height, 0, title_str)
        painter.end()


app = QApplication([])
fig1 = MyGLView()
fig1.show()
app.exec()


This seems to be screen based drawing, is there a way to draw it axis-based?

Opengl support in pg is limited. If you want to add axis base label you have to inherit from GLGraphicsItem and implement your own code to render text and proper transformation. You can find few GraphicItetms already implemented in pg and based on that create you own GL label.
